# Module will not run. Attempting to print text and take a input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this module and cannot see whats wrong with it. Btw im new to programming and python.

```
# functions.py

def MM():
    return print("""
 _______________
|               |
|   MAIN MENU   |
|     Save      |
|     Load      |
|    Options    |
|     Exit      |
|_______________|""")
    MMInput = input("")
    if MMInput == "Save".lower :
        return "save"
    elif MMInput == "Load".lower :
        return "load"
    elif MMInput == "Options".lower :
        return "options"
    elif MMInput == "Exit".lower :
        return "exit"
```

Running the module

```
import functions

Command1 = input("What do you want to do")
if Command1 == "menu".lower:
    print("Opening Menu")
    functions.MM
```

Comment: Your indentation looks like it needs some work, but it's probably that you're not actually calling `MM`, and it should be `functions.MM()` - just guessing though as you haven't told us what it's doing, what any error is, and what you expect...

Comment: Also, *all* of your `lower` calls aren't being called. Python does not have the same behaviour that perl/ruby have. If you want a method called on an object, you have to append `()` to the method name. Think of `()` as the "call" operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a function with opening and closing parenthesis:

```
functions.MM()
```

There is a big difference with or without parenthesis:

```
>>> def func():
         return 42
>>> func
<function __main__.func>

>>> func()
42
```